# Laptop getting crashed after georeferencing on v 3.18

Tags: qgis-3, openstreetmap, georeferencing, macos

I just started using QGIS  a few weeks ago. Whenever I do georeferencing on OSM using some toposheet and then start the georeferencing, my laptop gets stalled. I have to restart the laptop everytime in order to close QGIS. My laptop is a MacBook.  I need to do georeferencing for my assignments.

Comment: Have you tried using 3.16,which is the current LTR version?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works